# Help me identify this tablet Vivax TPC 8150

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

Yes, this is a bit out of topic but I need to identify this tablet VIVAX TPC-8150

AND YES BEFORE YOU ASK I DID ALLOT OF RESEARCH BEFORE DOING THIS.

All I need is a update image that will remove a adware/virus stuck in the /system folder or partition (I don't even care).

And no I can't open the tablet because it has a fully metal cover.

The closest thing I found (by build number is MK808b *which isn't even a tablet*)

System specs:

```
Android 4.2.2 Jellybean
Dual Core ARMv7 A9 Rockchip 3066 Processor @1.5 GHz
1 GB of DDR-3 RAM
8" TFT 1024x768 4:3 display
HDMI 1.2 (I think)
USB-OTG 2.0
Bluetooth 4.0
Micro-SDHC slot
...etc..etc
```

To help out I discovered a few things:

1. How to root this beast (King root)
2. How to get in recovery mode (Hold Vol. Up and Power and after boot screen let go of Power)

Misc info:

Recovery system v4.2.41

```
C:\Users\NotGettingMyUsername>adb shell "cat /system/build.prop | grep "product""
ro.product.model=TPC-8150
ro.product.brand=rk30sdk
ro.product.name=rk30sdk
ro.product.device=rk30sdk
ro.product.board=rk30sdk
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=rockchip
ro.product.locale.language=hr
ro.product.locale.region=HR
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=rk30sdk
ro.product.usbfactory=TPC-8150
ro.product.version=1.0.0
ro.product.ota.host=www.rockchip.com:2300
```

All I need is a similar to model (WHICH IS COMPATIBLE) to reflash the device.

Also if possible get CWM or TWRP running on it :)

Any help will be appreciated :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer and may give you a head start, by way of correct product model details

- **Retail Branding:** SK Telesys
- **Marketing Name:** ITP-R208W
- **Device:**  rk30sdk
- **Model:** ITP-R208W

**Source:** PDF at this link  [List of all devices supported by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)

Seems to be a Chinese product called ["Thinkle"](http://www.raystuff.com/default/products/products.php?com_board_basic=read_form&com_board_idx=9&m=3&sm=30&&com_board_search_code=&com_board_search_value1=&com_board_search_value2=&com_board_page)

This [Russian site](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://kudievskaja.ru/drayver-rk30sdk.php&ei=k27iPrtC&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=197&ts=1452646260&sig=ALL1Aj7TRmJDATtX56Vt68qo9M1mZPwIwg) points to github source when I googled for custom ROM